# Looking for a prototype slider/carousel

Tags: javascript, slider, prototypejs, carousel, scriptaculous

I'm looking for a slider/carousel which uses PrototypeJs / script.aculo.us

I've found this:

http://www.protoshow.net/

But I'm looking for functionality which has the ability to display multiple "slides" at once, i.e. more of a carousel effect.

I'd also like the ability to define how many slides are skipped by pressing next.

**Please do not recommend:** https://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/

That code is not fully functional and has been split into multiple branches on github, none of which can functionally skip more than a single slide at a time, or follow proper continuous or "circular" movement, i.e. slide 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 etc.

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ported the Bootstrap (2.3.2) components to PrototypeJS/Script.aculo.us, which does a very nice carousel

repo https://github.com/jwestbrook/bootstrap-prototype

examples http://cwaadmin.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Unless I am mistaken I do not see the ability to display more than one slide at a time? Also, only single skip supported.

Comment: Yes that's the case - I wanted to give you another option besides the 2 you already mentioned - I know the code can be changed to support what you are looking for but it looks like you are looking for something unique

Comment: I'm looking for the carousel functionality as seen "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" - http://www.dx.com/p/solar-powered-waving-lucky-cat-9502 but running on PrototypeJs/script.aculo.us

Comment: Ah that's a unique behavior - i might have to build an extension that does that - it would be useful for Magento users as well

Comment: Ah yeah. Definitely something  lacking in the community. This is for a magento store :)